# Using static const class instance for a switch / case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, constants

I have a class which acts a little like an enum, each instance of it has a unique int value which starts at 0 and increments at every new instance.

```
class MyEnumLikeClass
{
    static int NextId = 0;

    static const MyEnumLikeClass FIRST;
    static const MyEnumLikeClass SECOND;

    const int val_;

public :
    MyEnumLikeClass() : val_(NextId++)
    {
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        return val_;
    }

    //other methods (usually getters) omitted for clarity
}
```

I am trying to use it in a switch case so that I can do something like

```
MyEnumLikeClass value;
switch(value)
{
    case MyEnumLikeClass::FIRST :
        break;
    case MyEnumLikeClass::SECOND :
        break;
    default :
}
```

I am getting "case value is not a constant expression" errors which seem to be because the compiler doesn't know the values at compile time.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Looks like you're recreating a C++11 `enum class`. You might be able to simply use that.

Comment: At least prior to C++11, you can't switch directly on objects unless they have a conversion to an integral type. (You would need to add an `operator int() const` for example, and even then you wouldn't be able to use these instances in a case statement unless both the object and operator were `constexpr`, and for that you need C++11 anyway, so...)

Comment: "Is there any way to get something like this to work?" - how alike are we talking - hard to know what's acceptable when we have no idea why you're trying to do this rather than say using an actual enum....

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TonyD edited wording slightly.  That switch case example is exactly what I would like to have work.

Comment: @Angew from my understanding enum class is limited to integral types.  The benefit of doing this custom enum-like class is that I get to add methods to it and other members (which are omitted from the example for clarity, added a comment to the question to show this).

Comment: @Godfather: yes, enums are limited to integral types, but so are case statements....  You can define custom functions for enums even if they're not in a class... e.g. `operator<<(iostream&, My_Enum)`, `operator|(My_Enum e1, My_Enum e2)` etc..  Giving the exact details and scope of what you're trying to achieve would be an excellent idea - a list of representative types, functions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to a `case` statement must be an integral constant expression prior to C++11. The easiest way to do that is to use a `const int` or an actual `enum`. If you're using C++11 then you can simply use the built-in `enum class` support. See the [scoped enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).